# Default text shown on spinner but hide from drop down list - Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to show first item as a default text on spinner but in the drop down list that item is not shown like there is arraylist

```
     final ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("number");
    spinnerArray.add("one");
    spinnerArray.add("two");
    spinnerArray.add("three");
```

The number is always shown as a default text on spinner but after clicking on spinner there is one, two, three is shown in drop down list. when we select any number one, two three the default text number is not changed. How can i do it?

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapte = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

     adapte.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spin.setAdapter(adapte);

     spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
     {
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) 
         { 

         }

         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
         }
    });
```

Comment: I cannot find a single question mark in your "question"...

Comment: I think he wants to show `"number"` only the first time but not in the spinner dropdown. But, of course, this is a long guess.

Comment: Thanx for your reply and sorry for that please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it show the default as Number..
May be this help you

String[] priceString = { "Number", "one, "two"};

Spinner priceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.price_spinner);
ArrayAdapter priceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(               this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,priceString);      priceSpinner.setAdapter(priceAdapter);